# Transicion a elementos creados dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, css3, promesas, asincronismo

Estoy creando un sistema para subir imágenes con drag and drop, la idea es que cada imagen se vaya agregando vaya apareciendo en una cuadricula, utilizo promesas para que la imagen solo se aparezca cuando ya este cargada con el evento onload, pero no consigo que aparezca con una transición suave.
Dejo un ejemplo simple del problema

```js
let cont = document.getElementById('container')
let btn = document.getElementById('addEl')
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  let newEl = document.createElement('div')
  newEl.classList.add('elemento')
  cont.appendChild(newEl)
  newEl.classList.add('visible')
})
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.elemento {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease.in;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
<button type="button" id="addEl">Agregar Elemento</button>
```

En medida de lo posible prefiero no usar librerías.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código CSS está bien (salvo por tu error tipográfico `ease.in` en lugar de `ease-in`). La razón por la cual no se visualiza aún añadiendo un delay a la transición (`opacity 2s ease-in 2s`) se debe a cómo un elemento es renderizado en el documento.

Cuando agregas el elemento al DOM programáticamente, en ese instante se mantiene información de un estado anterior a este suceso, es por eso que cuando aplicas la clase `visible` no se realiza la transición. Para hacer que se produzca la transición debes **forzar un repintado** en el documento para que éste actualice su estado.

**Ejemplo**

```js
let cont = document.getElementById('container')
let btn = document.getElementById('addEl')
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  let newEl = document.createElement('div')
  newEl.classList.add('elemento')
  cont.appendChild(newEl)
  newEl.clientHeight // forzamos un repintado
  newEl.classList.add('visible')
})
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.elemento {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
<button type="button" id="addEl">Agregar Elemento</button>
```

También puedes hacerlo agregando la clase luego de unos cuantos milisegundos:

```
setTimeout(() => newEl.classList.add('visible'), 100);
```

No te recomiendo usar este último porque la cantidad de tiempo para que el DOM se repinte se ve afectada por varios factores, lo cual no te permite saber con exactitud cuándo pasará.

---

Las propiedades que forzan un repintado son las siguientes:

- Propiedades `offset`: `offsetTop`, `offsetLeft`, `offsetWidth` y `offsetHeight`.
- Propiedades `scroll`: `scrollTop`, `scrollLeft`, `scrollWidth` y `scrollHeight`.
- Propiedades `client`: `clientTop`, `clientLeft`, `clientWidth` y `clientHeight`.